# How to post this type of data in JSON Object

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have to post this type of data into Json. I don't want to convert cat in string. I only want single quote of item enclosing with double quote.

```
{"p02bvsd":"cal_dis","ovpsc7s":{"cat":["'Furniture'", "'Bikes'", "'Others'"]}}
```

**My Json**

```
      JSONObject jsonobject1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonobject.put("p02bvsd", "cal_dis");
        jsonobject.put("ovpsc7s", jsonobject1);
        jsonobject1.put("cat", hCategory);
```

Here hCategory is Hashset.

I want to json like this

```
{"p02bvsd":"cal_dis","ovpsc7s":{"cat": ["'Furniture'", "'Bikes'", "'Others'" ]}}
```

Comment: Can you share what you are trying now with relevant code snippets? What are you using to convert?

Comment: @brandonx question updated, Please take a look

Comment: Please make it clear what output you are getting currently vs desired output.

Comment: Ok but what is the output now?

Comment: I think that the problem is that `jsonobject1` is being modified before being added to `jsonobject`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
        jsonobject.put("p02bvsd", "cal_dis");
JSONObject jsonobject1 = new JSONObject();
List <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
list.add("Furniture");
list.add("Bikes");
list.add("Others");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        array.put(list.get(i));
}

try {
    jsonobject1.put("cat", array);
} catch (JSONException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

jsonobject.put("ovpsc7s", jsonobject1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "{\"p02bvsd\":\"cal_dis\",\"ovpsc7s\":{\"cat\":[\"\'Furniture\'\", \"\'Bikes\'\", \"\'Others\'\"]}}";

JSONObject wholeThing = new JSONObject(myString); // contains {"p02bvsd":"cal_dis","ovpsc7s":{"cat":["'Furniture'", "'Bikes'", "'Others'"]}}
JSONObject jsonp02bvsd = wholeThing.getJSONObject("p02bvsd"); // contains {"p02bvsd":"cal_dis"}
JSONObject jsonovpsc7s = wholeThing.getJSONObject("ovpsc7s"); // contains {"ovpsc7s":{"cat":["'Furniture'", "'Bikes'", "'Others'"]}
JSONArray jsonCatArray = jsonp02bvsd.getJSONArray("cat");  // contains ["'Furniture'", "'Bikes'", "'Others'"]
String first = jsonCatArray.getString(0); // contains 'Furniture'
```